# ServiceStack detecting user agent

Tags: c#, servicestack

I find some code in ss-includes.js from miniprofiler not working with IE. So I am wondering if I can do something like this in the SS Razor page:

```
@if(!UserAgent.IsIE) { //or however we can detect the browser agent
    ServiceStack.MiniProfiler.Profiler.RenderIncludes().AsRaw();
}
```

### Edit:

```
<!--[if !IE]>
    @ServiceStack.MiniProfiler.Profiler.RenderIncludes().AsRaw()
<![endif]-->
```

This will do the patch for now, but it would be nice to deal with it on the server side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the UserAgent with:

```
base.Request.UserAgent
```

With your own extension method you can get it to something like:

```
@if(!UserAgent.IsIE()) { ... }
```

But you should be escaping `@ServiceStack.MiniProfiler.Profiler.RenderIncludes().AsRaw()` in all cases, not just IE.